# Función generador de código secuencia en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo esta función que me genera el código de una devolucion pero no me inserta el mismo número, es decir `D0000001`, y quiero que cuando la ejecute desde el cursor que si ya tengo `D0000001` me imprima `D0000002` que es la siguiente, la función es esta:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FT_COD_DEVOLUCION](@dato as varchar(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AUTOINCREMENTO INT, @NUMERO VARCHAR(16), @CODIGO VARCHAR(16)

            SET @CODIGO=SUBSTRING(@dato,1,9)

        SELECT @AUTOINCREMENTO = ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(NoDocumento,3))),0) FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE TIPODOCUMENTO = 'Devolucion' 
                and NoDocumento  like 'D%'

            SET @AUTOINCREMENTO = @AUTOINCREMENTO + 1

        SELECT @NUMERO = RIGHT('000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @AUTOINCREMENTO),3)
            SET @CODIGO = RTRIM(@CODIGO) + RTRIM(@NUMERO)

        RETURN @CODIGO
    END

GO
```

Comment: ¿Y que valor esta retornado ahora la función? ¿Por otro lado, tienes claro que múltiples conexiones concurrentes obtendrían siempre el mismo número? ¿Has revisado si `SELECT * FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE TIPODOCUMENTO = 'Devolucion' and NoDocumento  like 'D%'` retorna datos?

Comment: SELECT @AUTOINCREMENTO = ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(NoDocumento,3))),0) FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE TIPODOCUMENTO = 'Devolucion' 
                and NoDocumento  like 'D%'
Esta funcion la que tengo aqui me verifica si hay registros que cumpla con esa condicion y me selecciona el maximo es decir si tengo 3 deberia ponerme 4 no se por que no lo hace,

Comment: El select te retorna el valor máximo que tienes en una tabla, ¿has verificado cual es ese valor? si no retorna  datos @AUTOINCREMENTO será null. Por eso te preguntaba que valor retorna actualmente la función.

Comment: si te entiendo lo que pasa es que esa función la estoy ejecutando desde un curso la cual su valor debería cambiar porque, a medida que se va insertando, debería ir incrementando, eso es lo que yo creo que debe de hacer pero no lo hace, lo que me devuelve siempre es el mismo D0000001 y no deberia ser asi

Comment: Pero es el mismo resultado que lo que estoy haciendo lo que pasa es que en el curso que tengo en sql server, no se incrementa parece que la función no cambia el valor

Comment: si te devuelve `D0000001` es probable que el select no estaría encontrando datos, el MAX retorna NULL, por consiguientes,  @AUTOINCREMENTO va a valer 0 y luego al hacer  `SET @AUTOINCREMENTO = @AUTOINCREMENTO + 1`, el resultado será 1. Prueba `SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(NoDocumento,3))) FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE TIPODOCUMENTO = 'Devolucion and NoDocumento  like 'D%` y nos cuentas que valor obtienes.

Comment: lo intente, pero me sigue igual, porque cuando ejecuto el curso tiene 2 registros, lo cual me debería insertar D0000001 y D0000002 lo cual no lo hace, no se que es lo que esta pasando pero creo que no vuelve y verificar la cantidad de registros que hay

Comment: Una cosa es que haya dos registros y otra es que los estés recuperando correctamente con tu `SELECT`. Si siempre te devuelve `D0000001` simplemente es por que la inicialización que haces desde el `SELECT` te da 0. Por eso te decía que verificaras `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(NoDocumento,3))),0) FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE TIPODOCUMENTO = 'Devolucion'  and NoDocumento  like 'D%`fuera de la función a ver que te devuelve.

Comment: Me devuelve 0 porque no hay registros, lo que pasa es lo siguiente, se van a ir almacenado, conforme se vayan insertando es decir, si el select que hago es 0 como estoy incrementando la variable en la cantidad de registros que haya, es decir, cuando se inserte el primero se va a insertar con D0000001 y cuando se inserte el segundo va a tener un valor de D0000002, porque es lo correcto lo que devuelve el select porque no hay registro, si no hay tiene que estar en 0 por  obligacion, pero cuando exista 1 debe ponermelo en 2